# Leaving Namibia only a couple hours after the visa expired

Tags: visas, overstaying, south-africa, namibia

I have a visa for Namibia until the 18th of December. I would like to take a bus from Windhoek to Capetown that leaves Windhoek on December 18th in the afternoon. It would get me to the NAM/SA-border at around 2 a.m. on December 19th.

What will likely happen at the border? Is this seriously not a good idea?
Is it possible to extend the visa for only a couple of days?

Comment: What did you do at the end? Did you just take the bus with the Visa expiring within 24 hours? Sounds like you a SA citizen? They wouldn't even of cared or noticed from my experience

Comment: I alsked the Namibian MLR for an extension but they told me it will not be a problem. So I will just take the bus, see what happens and state my experence here.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to post the solution: I did not have any problems at the border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293820-i9680-k5992379-Visa_overstay-Namibia.html):

> We have had a few cases with tourist overstaying there visas, (although normally only with a few days). I suggest you contact HA as soon as possible. To get a normal tourist visa extended is not such a huge thing and normally they are quite lenient with this if you can provide proof that you are self sufficient and not working here.

Not *very* recent (02 January 2013, 10:29) but the user name (AfricanProfileSaf) and location (Windhoek) add credibility.

> What will likely happen at the border?

Hopefully nothing significant at all, since you will have new visa by then.

> Is this seriously not a good idea?

Yes. Even if you have no plans to return that might change and a "black mark" from one country could have implicatios for your attempting to enter others.

> Is it possible to extend the visa for only a couple of days?

Yes. By far the preferred option.

Answer (score 5):

The information provided by @pnuts is correct, according to various web sites, although absent from the [Ministry of Home Affairs and Immigration](http://www.mha.gov.na/en/visas) web site.

Getting an extension requires a visit to its Windhoek offices in the Cohen Building on Kasino Street (at the corner of Independence Avenue). Kasino Street is between Independence and Luderitz Street in Windhoek Central.

The [Cardboard Box Namibia organization](http://www.namibian.org/travel/namibia/visa.html) gives a good summary (and current in 2016):

> *Please note that the following information is correct at the time of writing (and is updated frequently), however these things do change frequently so it may be worth checking the current visa requirements before travelling to Namibia.*
>
> All visitors require a passport to enter Namibia. This passport must be valid for at least 6 months beyond the intended stay and have sufficient pages for entry and exit stamps. All visitors must also have a valid return ticket.
>
> Minimum Requirements for Tourists exempted from visa requirements to enter Namibia:
>
> - Be in possession of a valid passport which is valid for at least 6 months beyond intended departure date from Namibia
> - Be in possession of valid return / onward air ticket or proof of other means of transportation enabling him to leave Namibia
> - Entry into Namibia will be permitted for a maximum period of 90 days, (extension possible on application to The Ministry of Home Affairs during stay in Namibia.)
>
> Visitors from the following countries do not require visas for stays of up to 90 days:
>
> Angola, Austria, Australia, Belgium, Botswana, Brazil, Cuba, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Ireland, Japan, Kenya, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Russia, Spain, Switzerland, UK, USA, Mozambique, New Zealand, Portugal, Iceland, the Netherlands, Malaysia, Singapore, the Scandinavian countries, South Africa, Zambia and Zimbabwe.

In requesting an extension, you may be required to show your onward ticket, or evidence of sufficient funds. While no mention is made of the cost of an extension, if any, the current visa handing fee is N$80 ($5.75 US), and N$ 390 success fee ($28.00 US) might be charged. Perhaps fees could be waived as your extension would be for just one additional day.