# What happens if my Namibia visa expires and I'm still in the country?

Tags: south-african-citizens, visa-expiration, namibia

I am from South Africa and would like to know what happens in the case of my visa expiring tomorrow. I am currently in Namibia and am on a visitors visa. As I understand that, if you're from one of the SADC affiliated countries, then you don't need a visa. However, my visa expires tomorrow and I am currently waiting on money to purchase my flight ticket to go back.

Comment: Which country are you in? What type of visa do you have?

Comment: I am currently in Namibia and am on a Visitors visa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaving Namibia only a couple hours after the visa expired](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78500/leaving-namibia-only-a-couple-hours-after-the-visa-expired)

Comment: @BritishSam That question was not about a SADC (visa-free) national though.

Comment: just a stupid question chris I just want to know what does the above answer tell me or how does that relate to my question on what to do

Comment: @GlennStevens so you don't have a visa? do you mean your time allowed in Namibia is expiring?

Comment: I didn't think South African nationals required visitor visas in Namibia?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.